# How python dataframe is stored in memory

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I can not figgure out how dataframe be stored in memory so that it can easily be added new col or new row, and different type of cols.

And a specify question is that if i have a n * n dataframe which n is large. What actually happen
in computer memory if I add a new col or a new row, and which one cause longer time?

Comment: Essentially, there is something called a "block manager" underneath the hood that manages various numpy.ndarray objects. Adding a colum *can* happen more-or-less efficiently. Adding a row is always inefficient.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks, could you be more detailed or suggest some reference or artical?

Comment: The columns are `numpy` arrays.  Adding a column is just appending another array.  Adding a row means modifying every column array.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-design/blob/master/source/internal-architecture.rst) is helpful.

Comment: I have a situation that I have to add 100 columns to a 300million * 2000 dataframe. And I compare the speed of 

1. adding one by one using for loop 
2. using a list to store these new cols and np.concate as a new df, then pd.concat to the old one.

the second method is far much quicker that the first